# regex php special characters

Tags: php, regex

```
$word = file_get_contents('http://www.pixelmon-server-list.com/list.txt');
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.pixelmon-server-list.com/fleetyfleet.txt');
$found_dimensions = array(); // our array
$word_array = explode(' ', $word); // explode the list
foreach($word_array as $one_word) { // loop over it
    $str = 'DimensionName'.$one_word; // what are we looking for?
    if(strstr($content, $str) !== false) { // look for it!
        echo $one_word; // Just for demonstration purposes
        $found_dimensions[] = $one_word; // add to the array
    }
}
```

okay i have a list.text and a fleetyfleet.txt
both can be viewed here i didn't post them for space sake
http://pastebin.com/7hWDUG1b
but what  i want to do is find the words in list.txt but only add them to array if there prefix is Dimension�����Name� but the special characters make it kinda tough I'm not sure what i should do

Comment: The special characters do not show up in the question. Do you need to match them exactly, or is `DimensionName.{5}Name.` close enough as a match?

Comment: i think that would work how would i implement it tho

Comment: I cannot view the files (firewall issues). Can you post a couple of lines, and show what you want the output array to look like? Use `Dimension%%%%%Name%` to indicate "weird characters". Do you know how to use `preg_match`? It probably is what you need...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I needed to remove all non-ascii characters from a file. Here's the regex I used:

```
s/[^\x00-\x7F]//g
```

If you're on linux, here's a quick one-liner:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/[^\x00-\x7F]//g" list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Having to guess a little bit as I can't see the files from behind my firewall.  The following code might help you:

```
<?php
$f1 = explode("\n",file_get_contents("./file1.txt"));
$f2 = file_get_contents("./file2.txt");
$found = array();
foreach($f1 as $x) {
  $str = "/DimensionName.....$x./";
  if (strlen($x)>0) {
    if (preg_match($str, $f2, $matches)) {
      echo $matches[0]."\n";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

This prints out lines that include a pattern `DimensionName` followed by 5 "anything" followed by whatever word was read from the first file `file1.txt`.

If you need this to be further refined, please leave a comment.